# Terraform recreates the autoscaling permission when upgrading EKS cluster version

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-eks

I upgraded the EKS cluster version using the terraform eks module

```
  cluster_version                 = "1.15"
```

But the terraform plan also shows the changes related to the autoscaling IAM policies. Once, I upgrade the cluster plan I will also upgrade the worker node. But I am not sure why the terraform is showing the changes.

```
# module.eks.data.aws_iam_policy_document.autoscaling_policy will be read during apply
  # (config refers to values not yet known)
<= data "aws_iam_policy_document" "autoscaling_polciy"  {
      + id   = (known after apply)
      + json = (known after apply)

      + statement {
          + actions   = [
              + "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups",
              + "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingInstances",
              + "autoscaling:DescribeLaunchConfigurations",
              + "autoscaling:DescribeTags",
              + "ec2:DescribeLaunchTemplateVersions",
            ]
          + effect    = "Allow"
          + resources = [
              + "*",
            ]
          + sid       = "eksWorkerAutoscalingAll"
        }
      + statement {
          + actions   = [
```

Comment: Can you share your autoscaling policy definition?

Comment: This implies the AWS autoscaling policy was updated since your last deployment.